# Update the "flag" in target based on some rules from 2 source tables in Hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I want to update my "flag" column in my target table with "Y" and "N" based on rules and data present in the source table.

Rule 1 - If mood is "sad" in source table 1 then update "flag" as "N"

Rule 2- For all the ids and names present in source table 2 update the "flag" as "N".

Rule 3- If "dept" fields contains value as "rty" then also flag should be "N". This scenario is not there in screenshot but please answer this as well.

For all remaining fields the flag should be "Y".

Please find the attached screenshot for clear understanding.

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below using case when

```
    SELECT a.id,
       a.dept,
       a.mood,
       b.name,
       CASE
           WHEN a.mood='sad' THEN 'N'
           WHEN a.dept='ytr' then 'N'
           WHEN b.id IS NULL THEN 'N'
           ELSE 'Y'
       END AS flag
FROM sourcetable1 a
LEFT JOIN sourcetable2 b ON a.id=cast(b.id as int)
```

Comment: Thanks but this only covers rule 1. also i want both the source table to directly inset values to target table without joining source tables first. Both source table should independently update flag into target table

Comment: @VimarshThusu, it also cover rule 2 as you can see I also write when b.id is null that means when the sourcetable2 value is missing in sourcetable1 that time it will be flaged as 'N', but yes rule 3 is not cover here which I am updting now

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to be sure by just giving b.id is NULL will all the id's and name from source table 2 will have flag as N in my target table?

Comment: just a small correction, id in source table 2 is string and its int in source table 1 and target table

Comment: @VimarshThusu, yes giving b.id is NULL will all the id's and name from source table 2 will have flag as N in your target table and I also made the conversion for your string ID, so that will be converted to INT

Comment: instead of joining 2 source tables first can we directly deal with source table and target table.i mean source 1 and target and then source 2 and target

Comment: Can you help me with that?

Comment: @VimarshThusu, do you've any physical table for target table?

Comment: yes. also can these 3 rules work separately. also i want these rules to be applied directly onto the target table with joining 2 source tables

Comment: @VimarshThusu . . . This appears to do what you want in this question.  My recommendation is to accept this answer (but that is up to you).  Additional questions and refinements should go into a *new* question.